# What does code 99 using portqry mean?

Tags: batch-file, portqry

I am using portqry v2 into a batch file and when I catch the stderr from the .exe file, the code is 99.
 I know what does 1,2 and 3 code means, but 99 I have no idea... 
I was googleling it for a while but it seems that I am the only one with that issue.....

Could you help me please ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft often has not good documented the exit codes respectively return values assigned to errorlevel variable for their console applications like [PortQry version 2.0](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/832919). Also Microsoft's [Portqry Remarks](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc759580.aspx) TechNet article explains only the errorlevels 0, 1 and 2.

But take a look on [Can I auto-install or deploy Splunk onto all my remote Windows servers?](http://answers.splunk.com/answers/434/can-i-auto-install-or-deploy-splunk-onto-all-my-remote-windows-servers) A user posted there a large batch file with the lines:

```
IF %ERRORLEVEL% == 99 goto CantResolve

:CantResolve
cls
echo Unable to resolve the Splunk DNS addresses (%DNSLOCATION%).
echo Please verify that the DNS settings are correct
```

It looks like exit code 99 means the IP address for the specified domain name cannot be resolved by DNS.

Comment: Thanks so much ,you made my day.That is a good answer with a really nice example, I own you a beer, I still don´t be able to mark that answer as usefull but i will do as soon as possible.
have a nice day